# How to use awk or sed to replace specific word under certain profile

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

a file contains data in the following format,  Now I want to chang the value of showfirst under XYZ section. how to achieve that with sed or awk or grep?

I thought of line number or second appearance but that's not going to be constant In future file can contain hundreds of such profile so it has to be user based.

I know that I can extract 1st line after 'XYZ' pattern but I want it to be field based. 
Thanks for help

```
[ABC]
showfirst =0
showlast=10

[XYZ]
showfirst=10
showlast=3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with sed following command solved my problem for every user,

```
sed '/.*\[ABC\]/,/^$/ s/.*showfirst.*/showfirst=20/' input.conf
```

syntax goes as sed [address] command

`'/.*\[ABC\]/,/^$/`  : This generates address range pointing to region starting from [ABC] up to next first blank line. Search for string will be done in this particular range only.

`s/.*showfirst.*/showfirst=20/:` This search for any line having showfirst in it and replace entire line with showfirst=20

Comment: It's the right approach if there is only one `showfirst=` occurrence per section. (I don't know why, I thought there could be multiple `showfirst=` and that only first occurrence should be replaced...)

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed '/^\[XYZ\]/,/^showfirst *=/{0,//!s/.*/showfirst=20/}' file
```

**How it works:**

- `/^\[XYZ\]/,/^showfirst *=/`: address range that matches lines from `[XYZ]` to next `^showfirst`
- `//` is for lines matching above addresses(`[XYZ]` and `showfirst=10`). So  `0,//!`: NOT in the first matching line(that is `showfirst=10` line)
- `s/.*/showfirst=20/`: replace line with `showfirst=44`

Comment: will you please elaborate it .

Comment: This works fine for XYZ profile but when ABC's profile has to be changed it shows following output,                                                                              
 sed '/^\[ABC\]/,/^showfirst=/{0,//!s/.*/showfirst=20/}' input.conf                         
[ABC]
showfirst=20
showfirst=20
showfirst=20
showfirst=20
showfirst=20
showlast=3

Comment: It's because of the space in`showfirst =0` that the regex did not match. I edited, It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -v val='50' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} /^\[.*\]$/{ flag = ($1 == "[XYZ]"?1:0) } 
       flag && $1 == "showfirst" { $2 = val } 1' file

[ABC]
showfirst =0
showlast=10

[XYZ]
showfirst=50
showlast=3
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk. All parameterized:

```
$ awk -v l='XYZ' -v k='showfirst' -v v='666' '  # parameters lable, key, value
BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }                            # delimiters
/\[.*\]/ { f=0 }                                # flag down @new lable
$1=="[" l "]" { f=1 }                           # flag up @lable
f==1 && $1==k { $2=v }                          # replace value when flag up and match
1' file                                         # print 
[ABC]
showfirst =0
showlast=10

[XYZ]
showfirst=666
showlast=3
```

Man, even I feel confused looking at that code.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the record separator (`RS`) to the empty stiring, `awk` will read a whole record at a time, assuming the records are double-newline separated.

So for example you can do something like this:

```
awk -v k=XYZ -v v=42 '$1 ~ "\\[" k "\\]" { sub("showfirst *=[^\n]*", "showfirst=" v) } 1' RS= ORS='\n\n' infile
```

Output:

```
[ABC]
showfirst =0
showlast=10

[XYZ]
showfirst=42
showlast=3
```